# Get data from multiple lists using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, ajax, sharepoint-framework, react

My requirement is:

To pass listnames as an array to a method and concatenate the result after each success.

The problem is I'm not able to concatenate the result from the previous ajax call

```
handleClick = (ListName) => {
    var reactHandler = this;  

  jquery.ajax({ 

      url: this.props.siteUrl+ "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + ListName + "')/items" , 

      type: "GET", 

      headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'},


      success: function(resultData) { 

        ///logic???


       });

          }


      }, 

      error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

      } 

  });

  }
```

Comment: You can use AngularJS, check this similar question: [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/255197/70877](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/255197/70877)

Answer (score 0):

finally found the way to get list items.

```
var reactHandler = this; 
var listname = ["Asset Approval", "RemoteLists","testList","documentList"];

var i=0;
var itemArrays = {};

var feedPromises = [];
for (let index = 0; index < listname.length; index++){
    //start the process to get all the feeds and save their ajax promises into an array
    feedPromises.push(test(listname[index]));
}
function test(ListName) {


  //alert("getfeed ")
  return  jquery.ajax({
    url: reactHandler.props.siteUrl+ "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + ListName + "')/items" ,

    type: "GET", 

    headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'},

      success: function (resultData) {


              itemArrays[i] = resultData.d.results;

               ++i;

      }, 

  error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

  }
  });
}
var listData;
var flag=true;
// wait until all the feeds return data to continue
jquery.when.apply(this, feedPromises)
.done(function(){
    // when all the data calls are successful you can access the data via

    for (let index = 0; index < listname.length; index++) {

   alert(itemArrays[index])


    }

});
```